# Preinstalled Nextcloud on Ubuntu - Which Webserver?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, nextcloud

I have installed Nextcloud together with Ubuntu Server 22.04. Seems like it installed it via snap, as the files are located in /var/snap/... What Webserver does it use now?

I guessed it would use Apache2 as default webserver. But it seems like there is no Apache2 installed, as "service apache2 status" gave me no results....

Comment: I would expect it to have packed it's own http server? Could be nginx. You should be able to tell when checking the process table. Something like `ps aux`? For sure you can check the contents of that snap package: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979233/how-to-list-files-installed-by-a-snap-package